# Any way to get an event that is raised half-way before an animation completes?

Tags: windows-runtime

I have an animation that AutoReverses and am interested in getting an event half-way before it completes (I am trying to simulate flipping of a coin, and at half-way point I need to change image from heads to tails). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: why do you need an event? you can change the picture half way through the animation as Storyboard transition.

Answer (score 0):

For general solution to get an event half way would be to put something like an ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames and in a DiscreteObjectKeyFrame switch the value of a property like IsGoingUp, then in IsGoingUp property changed handler - react to that change - perhaps by raising an event.

For your specific problem - you can use two ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames with DiscreteObjectKeyFrame and just set the Visibility of one image to Collapsed in one of the animations and to Visible in the other one.